# Ignore cell for row insertion

Tags: smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

When creating a row to insert into Smartsheet, how does one ignore a cell?  The following example illustrates my point:

```
new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[2].Id, Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate)).Build()
```

If the data I'm fetching doesn't return a valid date, I want to let this cell default to its empty value, i.e., ignore the building of the cell.  Is this possible, and if so, what would be the syntax for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the array of cells they you pass to the RowBuilder, simply exclude that particular cell/columnID.

You'll need to create some logic to determine if the data you're adding meets your criteria of "valid", and exclude that column if it does not.

If you just mean "will Smartsheet handle this data" valid, you can set the 'allowPartialSuccess' parameter to true. This will still add the other cells, while the invalid cell will be empty.

http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#add-row(s)

Comment: Thanks much - that helped!